# INNER JOIN syntax for mySQL using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin, inner-join

```
SELECT Question.userid, user.uid
FROM `question`
WHERE NOT `userid`=2
LIMIT 0, 60
INNER JOIN `user`
ON `question`.userid=`user`.uid
ORDER BY `question`.userid
```

returns Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `User` ON `question`.userid=`user`.uid ORDER BY `question`.userid' at line 5

Can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query doesn't look valid. You may want to try the following:

```
SELECT      `question`.userid, `user`.uid
FROM        `question`
INNER JOIN  `user` ON `question`.userid = `user`.uid
WHERE       `userid` <> 2
ORDER BY    `question`.userid
LIMIT       0, 60
```

Comment: Nailed it on the head! You sir are my savior for the day!

Comment: Out of interest, do you know what was wrong with line 5? i.e. INNER JOIN ON

Comment: @David: Your only syntax error was `WHERE NOT userid=2` where you had to use `WHERE userid <> 2`. Otherwise it was simply the order of the clauses that was incorrect. `LIMIT` must always be the last. The `WHERE` clause needs to follow the `FROM` and all the `JOIN`s, etc. The `INNER JOIN` syntax was fine. It was just at the wrong place, since it had a `WHERE` before it.

Comment: Ah thanks, though the 'WHERE NOT' clause actually was valid, I was using it before adding the INNER JOIN part, if that makes sense.

Comment: @David: You're right, it is valid! Wasn't thinking :) ... It was just the ordering then.